# Disable RightClick on every tag except textarea and textfield

Tags: javascript, block, right-click

I found this cross browser script

```
<script language=JavaScript>
<!--
var message="Function Disabled!";

function clickIE4(){
    if (event.button==2){
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }
}

function clickNS4(e){
    if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
        if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
            alert(message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if (document.layers){
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
    document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
// --> 
</script>
```

How can I say that the rightlick should work on every textarea and on every textfield tag?

PS: I know, users hate it when you deactivate the rightclick! But on my page it is very useful.

Comment: Arrrrgh. Deactivating right click is terrible and useless. Do yourself a favour and don't do it!

Comment: .. and that script is terrible as well. It's from, like, 1998 or something - if you *must* do this, I would recommend choosing a different, more modern one

Comment: Pekka is right on both accounts.  The only reason I could imagine needing to disable right click would be if you had a game of some sort and wanted to have right-click map to some in-game action.  But the fact you editable text fields in your page has me thinking this isn't what you're doing.  So just don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOte on some of the browsers the variable e will not be set and there are various such problems around the same.. anyways coming to the question you  need to get the target type of the event and then check whether it is a text or a textbox..

this is how you retrieve the target of an event:

```
function eventHandler(e)
{
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/CG2QA/2/)

thus with the target type with you, you could handle the condition to disable the right click as follows:

```
function checkIfTypeIsTextOrTextArea(event)
{
    var targ;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
return targ==="text" || targ="textarea";
}

function eventHandler(e)
{
    var evt=e;
    if(!e)
    evt=window.event;
    if(!checkIfTypeIsTextOrTextArea(evt))
        //code to disable right click
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Pekka, disabling right click is nearly always the wrong thing to do.  'Would love to hear what it is you need this for (and explain to you why you don't need it. ;) ).  But, if you must, at least use this nice-n-tight JS so you don't look like a complete n00b:

```
// Disable right-click everywhere except INPUT and TEXTAREA elements
document.body.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  var el = e.srcElement || e.target;
  if (!(/textarea|input/i).test(el.nodeName)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: That method still works *if* you use `document.oncontextmenu` instead of `document.body.oncontextmenu`. Works perfectly in CEF-based applications.